# AngularJS: How to pass values from Controller to Service Method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have a controller which is dependent on a `TransactionService`. One of the method is

```
$scope.thisMonthTransactions = function () {
    $scope.resetTransactions();
    var today = new Date();
    $scope.month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    $scope.year = today.getFullYear().toString();
    $scope.transactions = Transaction.getForMonthAndYear();
};
```

The `TransactionService` looks like

```
angular.module('transactionServices', ['ngResource']).factory('Transaction', function ($resource, $rootScope) {
    return $resource('/users/:userId/transactions/:transactionId',
        // todo: default user for now, change it
        {userId: 'bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810', transactionId: '@uuid'},
        {
            getRecent: {method: 'GET', params: {recent: true}, isArray: true},
            getForMonthAndYear: {method: 'GET', params: {month: 5, year: 2013}, isArray: true}
        });
});
```

As you can see the method `getForMonthAndYear` depends on two parameters `month` and `year`, which are hardcoded right now as `params: {month: 5, year: 2013}`. How can I pass this data from my controller?

I tried injecting `rootScope` in `TransactionService`, but that did not help(meaning I do not know how to use it probably).

Also [Angular ngResource documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) doesn't recommend any way to perform this.

Can someone please guide here?

**UPDATE**
My Controller looks like

```
function TransactionsManagerController($scope, Transaction) {

    $scope.thisMonthTransactions = function () {
        $scope.resetTransactions();
        var today = new Date();
        $scope.month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString();
        $scope.year = today.getFullYear().toString();

        var t = new Transaction();
        $scope.transactions = t.getForMonthAndYear({month: $scope.month});
    };
}
```

and I change service method to

```
getForMonthAndYear: {method: 'GET', params: {month: @month, year: 2013}, isArray: true}
```

I look at the `console.log` and it says

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL transaction.js:11
Uncaught Error: No module: transactionServices
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining params in the resource constructor are only necessary when the call needs to have a  default when none is supplied.  Any param passed in to the method is appended as a query param, regardless of whether it has a default value defined. The '@' means that the params value is replaced by what gets returned in the JSON response, so your @uuid makes sense, but not your @month.

Personally, I would just create the resource like so:

```
$resource('/users/:userId/transactions/:transactionId',
    // todo: default user for now, change it
    {userId: 'bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810', transactionId: '@uuid'},
    {
        getRecent: {method: 'GET', params: {recent: true}, isArray: true},
        getForMonthAndYear: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
```

Then add the query variables as needed by passing them in.  (Creating special method names is fine but not necessary so showing both ways below.)

```
var t = new Transaction();
$scope.recentTransactions = t.$get({recent:true}) //results in /users/bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810/transactions/?recent=true
$scope.recentTransactions = t.$getRecent(); //same thing as above
$scope.transactions = t.$get({month: $scope.month, year: $scope.year}); //results in /users/bd675d42-aa9b-11e2-9d27-b88d1205c810/transactions/?month=5&year=2013
$scope.transactions = t.$getForMonthAndYear({month: $scope.month, year: $scope.year}); //same as above... since no defaults in constructor, always pass in the params needed
```

Comment: I think his problem is not with the $resource, but rather the interaction between the controller and a service

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I ended up returning parametrized functions from my service, so the service looks like that

```
factory('MyService', function($resource) {
    return {
        id: function(param) { return $resource('/api/'+param+'/:id', {id: '@id'}); },
        list: function(param) { return $resource('/api/'+param); },
        meta: function(param) { return $resource('/api/meta/'+param); }
    }
})
```

and calling the service from the controller with:

```
$scope.meta = MyService.meta('url_param').query();
```

not sure this is the cleanest angular.js solution, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it is to inject the service into your controller:

```
angular.controller('controllerName', 
 ['$scope', 'Transaction',
   function($scope, transactionService) {
      ...
   }
]);
```

Then you can access an instance of your service through the transactionService parameter.

EDIT

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wFTTW/1/) Tell me if this is close enough to what you are trying to do

Comment: Can you please tell me how? I just tried and updated my question

Comment: @daydreamer: Your Transaction service lives in a module called 'transactionServices'. Make sure that the module that your controller is defined in specifies it as its dependency. angular.module('myCtrlModule', ['transactionServices']).controller(...